# Explaining syntax of makefile

Tags: makefile

can anyone help me in interpreting the following makefile:

```
# compiler
FC = gfortran

# compile flags
FCFLAGS = -c -ffixed-line-length-72 -std=gnu -Wline-truncation -Wunused-variable

# link flags
FLFLAGS = 

# module files 
MODULES = Calculator.f

# object files 
OBJS  = Calculator.o
OBJS += Main.o Common.o Io.o

# program name
PROGRAM = calFap

all: $(PROGRAM) 

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS) 
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.f
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^

mod: $(MODULES) 
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

What does this mean:

```
# module files 
MODULES = Calculator.f
```

Is this just a kind of placeholder? So MODULES is "linked" to Calculator.f ? The file Calculator.f already exists.

```
# object files 
OBJS  = Calculator.o
OBJS += Main.o Common.o Io.o
```

So here I create a variable and I put in Calculator.o Main.o Common.o Io.o  . But in my folder they do not exist up to now?

```
all: $(PROGRAM)
```

So the internet tells me, that "all" as a target is used in order to compile the whole program? But as far as I understand, makefiles are there for only compiling those parts of a programm which have changed?

```
$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS) 
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

If there is a change in one of the OBJS files then something should be compiled. But I do not get the part with "-o $@ $^" . Maybe all objects which have changed?

```
%.o: %.f
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

If there is a change in one of the .f files ...? I don't get this line.

For your help I would be really happy.

Thanks Helmut

Comment: What a great idea, thank you so much for your link

Comment: You are asking for an introductory makefile tutorial; many such tutorials are on the web, but this site is designed for more specific questions.

Comment: `make` knows plain textual variables much like any other programming language (which it is), so `MODULES = Calculator.f` is just an assignment to the variable `MODULES`. The only caveat is that *using the contents* of this variable needs to be told to `make` by using the `$(MODULES)` form, which in this case will evaluate to the string `Calculator.f`. That there is a file behind this name is unbeknownst to `make` unless you use this variable in a place where normally a file name goes (e.g. in a target or prerequisite)

Comment: @HelmutK. No problem. Read it, try figure it out, then come back with a specific question or problem. Good luck.